# Google is indexing only the title and meta description of webpage on its first try

Tags: googlebot, search-engine-indexing, google-index

Recently I posted one article in my blog and Google indexed it the next day. However, they did not index the whole article, they just indexed the title  and meta description. The content inside the blog post was not indexed.

First I tried to copy paste my first paragraph from blog post in Google search but it was not indexed, then I tried this query on Google search `my-post-content site:mydomain.com/my-blog-post/`. But google return nothing.

Today I just copied and pasted my first paragraph in search box and it *is* indexed. Is it usual for Google not to index the whole page in first try?

Comment: When Google fetches a page, it takes the whole page, It has too, Google has no choice. It stores the HTML code and then begins processing it fairly quickly. What I rather suspect is that the data center you are hitting is not up to date yet. Think about it. It is not at all possible to fetch the HTML page from California and have all the data centers all over the world updated immediately. It is not possible considering the vast amount of processing and data. I am not sure how long it should take a giant like Google, however, it may be that things are slowing down more these days. Who knows?

Comment: Good point closetnoc, when I will publish new blog post, then I will check my index on Google.com not to google.co.in :) Cheers :D

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior from Google before.   But then again, I don't usually check to see if pages are indexed just after they are first crawled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this happens with a ton of other websites. Even when you change the meta description, it can take a while before Google actually shows up the new Titles and Descriptions.

You need to be a little patient with Google :)

Comment: Google already index the title and meta description of my blog post but the question is they did not index the body content in first try of crawling. I have also ask that question in official hangout and they said "it should not happen in general, we crawl whole page but pass the URL of your blog post we will look on it" But as I said it is index in the second day. The main thing here is why they crawl just half information, might you miss the comment discussion.